# How sed command used in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have shell script where I am using SED command, I am Reading file and remove all character after HELLO from each statement, But still I am getting null value

```
file=commit.txt
    while IFS= read line
    do
            commitid=$line | sed "s/  HELLO.*'[^']*'/ /"
             echo $line | sed "s/  HELLO.*'[^']*'/ /"   /* Not removing character*/
            echo $commitid /* Returning null*/
    done <"$file"
```

my file has 2 statement

```
dummy statement Hello world 
dummy 1 statement Hello Mike
```

expected output

```
dummy statement 
dummy 1 statement
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Without showing us sample inputs and sample outputs or script's sample output, we can't help you that much to be honest, please add them in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  updated

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if that helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a job of simple `sed` as follows.

```
file="commit.txt"
sed 's/Hello.*//g' "$file"
```

Comment: That's what I wanted, Thank you :)

Comment: @Ganesh, glad that it helped you, cheers and happy learning :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is "command substitution" in bash. For this you have to enclose your command with `$()`

```
while IFS= read line
do
    val1=$(echo "$line"|sed 's/HALLO/TEST/')
    val2=$(echo "$val1"|sed 's/TEST/XYZ/')
    echo $val2
done < test.txt
```

I used a simpler sed expression to see it works with my text file. As you can see, I first replace HALLO with TEST and in next line TEST with XYZ. So you can see that the variable content is handled and passed to the next evaluation.

Input:

```
eins HALLO zwei
eins HALLO zwei
eins HALLO zwei
eins HALLO zwei
```

Output:

```
eins XYZ zwei
eins XYZ zwei
eins XYZ zwei
eins XYZ zwei
```

Update:
After you provide your input data, the script can be:

```
while IFS= read line
do
    val=$(echo "$line"|sed 's/Hello.*$//')
    echo $val
done < test.txt
```

But indeed no need for a script here:

```
sed 's/Hello.*$//' test.txt > output.txt
```

did the same.